# ESME/SMSC message order

Tags: sms, smpp

If the ESME sends a PDU to the SMSC will the next response from the SMSC always be the answer to this PDU (let's say "submit_sm_resp" for "submit_sm") or can it be that the SMSC sends me another message like "enquire_link" or "deliver_sm" before sending the "submit_sm_resp"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends mostly on vendor implementation, but SMPP can be either synchronous or asynchronous. Basicaly, if you connect as a transmitter, you will always get response as the first message after you send request. But if you have transceiver bind, you can get request from SMSC before it will send you back response to your submit_sm.

Comment: If you're satisfied with answer, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.